# Android R class resolved despited not being imported

Tags: android

Normally on Android you need to import the R class but in this project the class accesses R despite it's not being imported in that class, how does this work? If I copy that class to another project I have open Android Studio says I need to import the R class, how come?

[This](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/main/NavigationAdvancedSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/navigationadvancedsample/MainActivity.kt) is the class I'm talking about

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Normally on Android you need to import the R class

`import` is a language thing, more than an Android thing.

> but in this project the class accesses R despite it's not being imported in that class

The `package` attribute on the `<manifest>` element in `AndroidManifest.xml` is `com.example.android.navigationadvancedsample`. That means that `R` is code-generated as being in that package. The class that you refer to is also in that same package. And, in Java and Kotlin, you do not need to explicitly `import` classes in the same package as your own.

Answer (score 0):

You are able to use classes in the same package without import.
**In Java** you have access to public, package local and protected terms.
**In Kotlin** only public and internal.